# How do I change the time to Taipei?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert date to another timezone in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

How to  make this program get Taipei's time? Is their something to fix? or do I need to add some code for it?

```
var yudan = "";
var now = new Date();
var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
var date = now.getDate();
var year = now.getFullYear();
if (year < 2000) year = year + 1900;

document.write(year + "." + yudan + month + "." + date + ".");
```

---

```
document.write("<span id=\"yudan_clock\"><\/span>");
var now,hours,minutes,seconds,timeValue;
function yudan_time(){
now = new Date();
hours = now.getHours();
minutes = now.getMinutes();
seconds = now.getSeconds();
timeValue = (hours >= 12) ? " " : " ";
timeValue += ((hours > 12) ? hours - 0 : hours) + ":";
timeValue += ((minutes < 10) ? " 0" : " ") + minutes + ":";
timeValue += ((seconds < 10) ? " 0" : " ") + seconds + "";
document.getElementById("yudan_clock").innerHTML = timeValue;
setTimeout(yudan_time, 100);}
yudan_time();
```

Comment: You can change that `year` thing into just `var year = now.getFullYear();`, by the way. And the `setTimeout` should be more like `setTimeout(yudan_time, 100);`. Or just a `setInterval` with a delay of `1000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is getting the clock to show the time at Taipei, use the `getTimezoneOffset()` method. This lets you define how the offset in time between the UTC/GMT and the desired timezone (in Taipei, it's UTC+8). Then, you can use the set of UTC timing methods, like `now.getUTCMonth()` in place of `now.getMonth()`.

So this is how your code might look:

```
var yudan = "";
var now = new Date();
var month = now.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var date = now.getUTCDate();
var year = now.getUTCFullYear();
if (year < 2000) year = year + 1900;
document.write(year + "." + yudan + month + "." + date + ".");

document.write("<span id=\"yudan_clock\"><\/span>");
var now,hours,minutes,seconds,timeValue;
function yudan_time(){
now = new Date();
hours = now.getUTCHours() + (now.getTimezoneOffset()/60);
minutes = now.getUTCMinutes();
seconds = now.getUTCSeconds();
timeValue = (hours >= 12) ? " " : " ";
timeValue += ((hours > 12) ? hours - 0 : hours) + ":";
timeValue += ((minutes < 10) ? " 0" : " ") + minutes + ":";
timeValue += ((seconds < 10) ? " 0" : " ") + seconds + "";
document.getElementById("yudan_clock").innerHTML = timeValue;
setTimeout(yudan_time, 100);}
yudan_time();
```

Keep in mind, the `getTimezoneOffset()` method returns a value in minutes; for Taipei, it would return 480, so you need to divide by 60 to get the hours.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, It's very helpful:)  But my `getTimezoneOffset()` timezone is -8, so if -8/60=-480, then my time will be -2:58:00, that's wrong time now. Can i edit it to `hours = now.getUTCHours() + (now.getTimezoneOffset()/60)*-1`?

Comment: Yeah, you can definitely do that.

Comment: Thank you!!! It's very successful!!

Comment: I'm sorry. My friend said the time still wrong..., i don't know why...

Comment: hmm...perhaps you could describe your problem as an edit to this question?

Comment: She said the time is the computer's time.

Comment: oh, then there is no timezone offset. In that case, you won't need to use the `getUTC` methods or `getTimezoneOffset`.

Comment: But, if i don't need it, how do i get the true time?

Comment: You would just use the code you had earlier. That would give you the computer time, which is probably the closest thing to "true" time you can achieve with JavaScript. However, if you use your code, you would get the computer's time. If you use my code, you get the time at Taipei, regardless of where you are in the world.

Comment: Nop, my friend say the time is wrong...,I use your code.  [this](http://www.kukofashion.com.tw/)is my page, maybe you can take a look.